# ggplot override symbol in legend to just line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want just lines (not crosses) to show in my legend. [picture of plot with cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsIRc.png)

```
 example.dat <- data.frame(distance=c("short","medium","short","medium"),ubiquity = c(0.09,0.09,0.30,0.30),deltaAUC = c(-0.0095,-0.039,-0.0206,-0.045),lower=c(-0.0888,0.0299,-0.0089,0.09),upper=c(0.165,0.284,0.174,0.273))

ggplot(example.dat, aes(ubiquity, deltaAUC,colour=distance)) + 
 geom_line(aes(group=distance),size=1,position=position_dodge(0.02))+
geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.02),size=0)+
geom_linerange(aes(ymin=-(plogis(lower)-0.5), ymax=- (plogis(upper)-0.5)),position=position_dodge(0.02),size=1)+
theme_bw()+
theme(plot.title=element_text(margin=margin(t=40,b=-20),hjust=0.5),
    legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2),
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "black",size = .3),
    legend.title=element_blank())+
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=0,linetype=1)))+
ggtitle(NULL)+
ylab(NULL)+
xlab(NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `show.legend = FALSE` to the `geom` you don't want a legend for, e.g.:

```
geom_linerange(aes(ymin = -(plogis(lower)-0.5), ymax = - (plogis(upper)-0.5)), 
               position = position_dodge(0.02), 
               size = 1, 
               show.legend = FALSE)
```